Fine-tuning llama: Prompt tokenizer and chat template issue
alpaca_prompt = """Below is an instruction that describes a task, paired with an input that provides further context. Write a response that appropriately completes the request.

### Input:
{}

### Response:
{}"""

EOS_TOKEN = tokenizer.eos_token # Must add EOS_TOKEN
def formatting_prompts_func(examples):
    inputs       = examples["Context"]
    outputs      = examples["Response"]
    texts = []
    for input, output in zip(inputs, outputs):
        # Must add EOS_TOKEN, otherwise your generation will go on forever!
        text = alpaca_prompt.format(input, output) + EOS_TOKEN
        texts.append(text)
    return { "text" : texts, }
pass

from datasets import load_dataset
dataset = load_dataset("My_DATA_SET", split = "train")
dataset = dataset.map(formatting_prompts_func, batched = True,)

I am trying to fine tune llama3.1 using unsloth, since I am a newbie I am confuse about the tokenizer and prompt templete related codes and format. My data contains two key value pairs, Context and Response, I removed the ### Instruction:
{} from alpaca template. Where can I learn this data preparation and chat template stuff correctly. ChatGPT failed me already!
Apparently, my model is training with Input and Response only but the error loss seems to hover around 2.
